# Can't figure out why JS plugin isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to implement a JS modal window and have nearly copied the code for the plugin verbatim and it is still not working; the following is my code...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="avgrund.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="buttons">
        <a href="#" id="show" class="button left">Show it</a>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery
                            /1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.avgrund.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $('#show').avgrund({
            height: 200,
            holderClass: 'custom',
            showClose: true,
            showCloseText: 'Close',
            enableStackAnimation: true,
            onBlurContainer: '.container',
            template: '<p>So implement your design ' +
            'and place content here! If you want to ' +
            'close modal, please hit "Esc", click ' +
            'somewhere on the screen or use special ' +
            'button.</p>'
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The html file which contains this code is located in the same directory as all the required JS and CSS files. I believe I've brought everything to the bare-bone basics but can't figure out why this isn't working; what am I missing? Modal retrieved from http://labs.voronianski.com/jquery.avgrund.js/

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: in that case any other error in your browser console

Comment: I do get the following error 'Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'avgrund'' when calling the plugin here.... $('#show').avgrund({

Comment: @codingManiac it means the it does not recognize you'r js plugin, the problem is in this line: <script src="jquery.avgrund.js"></script> you need to change the src to the right path so the plugin can be loaded to page.

Comment: do you have the `jquery.avgrund.js` in the same directory as the html file

Comment: yes all files are located in the same directory, that's why this is confusing; I don't remember altering the plugin files either

Comment: @ArunPJohny I am also getting an error in the jquery.avgrund.js file at the doctype declaration of... 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < '

Comment: @codingManiac looks like your plugin file is corrupted.... download it again and try

Comment: @ArunPJohny tried that a couple of times with the same result.

Comment: @codingManiac check my answer and demo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replacing your avgrund script to this location , and if it works save it .

I have tested this and its working for me

```
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/voronianski/jquery.avgrund.js/master/jquery.avgrund.min.js"></script>
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/codingantGit/5j9zC/6/

Comment: you need to use http://rawgithub.com/ instead of `raw.github` because that sends the content-type set to text/plain instead of javascript for the majority of the time...

Comment: two questions; why does this work by referencing the URL but not locally? and how would I resolve the error of 'Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:'?

Comment: 1) may be the downloaded plugin file is corrupted , just save the file from the refernce URL , and keep in local it work for sure, 2) And the valid css file get it from here https://rawgithub.com/voronianski/jquery.avgrund.js/master/style/avgrund.css

Comment: Thank you very much both David and CodingAnt, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're adding up the invalid js files!

```
Valid js file: http://labs.voronianski.com/media/js/jquery.avgrund.js

Valid CSS: http://labs.voronianski.com/jquery.avgrund.js/avgrund.css
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/sunnykumar08/USD4Q/

Answer (score 0):

Forward slash and type:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.avgrund.js"></script>
```

Comment: ehh that directs the browser to search for the js in the parent directory, but its in the same directory as my html file

Comment: it would be `./jquery.avgrund.js` for same directory